# Metodo hashCode() de la clase Object

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo una gran curiosidad con respecto a dicho método,se que pertenece a la Clase object y por defecto tiene la siguiente forma.
public native  int hashCode ();
Dicho método por defecto devuelve una representación numérica de la dirección de memoria en la que se encuentra ubicado el objeto.Por ejemplo si yo tengo una Clase concreta digamos 'Cliente' ,al yo hacer una instancia de esta clase y llamar al método hashCode ()..
Cliente c=new Cliente();
System.out.println (c.hashCode ());
Esto imprimira  obviamente un valor entero que es una representación numérica de la dirección de memoria en la que sencuentra ubicado el objeto.Ya que la dirección de memoria de un objeto siempre será de formato hexadecimal.
Mi pregunta es.Es cierto todo esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este método viene a complementar al método [Equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) y sirve para comparar objetos de una forma más rápida en estructuras `Hash` ya que únicamente nos devuelve un número entero. Cuando Java compara dos objetos en estructuras de tipo hash (HashMap, HashSet etc) primero invoca al método [HashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) y luego el equals.

Si los métodos hashcode de cada objeto devuelven diferente Java no seguirá comparando y considerará a los objetos distintos. En el caso en el que ambos objetos compartan el mismo hashcode Java invocará al método `equals()` y revisará a detalle si se cumple la igualdad. De esta forma las búsquedas quedan simplificadas en estructuras hash.
[image: HashCode]

Muchas veces se nos olvida que la invocación a los métodos **equals** y **hashcode** forma parte intrínseca del framework de colecciones.

**¿Qué implica el hashcode?**

Algunas colecciones usan el valor Hashcode para ordenar y localizar a los objetos que están contenidos dentro de ellas. El hashcode es un numero entero, sin signo, que sirve en colecciones de tipo Hash para un mejor funcionamiento en cuanto a performance. `Este método debe ser sobrescrito en todas las clases que sobrescriban el método equals`, si no se quiere tener un comportamiento extraño al utilizar las colecciones de tipo Hash y otras clases. Si dos objetos son iguales según el método equals sobrescrito, estos deberían regresar el mismo hashcode. Por ejemplo:

```
package test;

public class Demo {

    private int boleta;

    public Demo(int boleta) {
        this.boleta = boleta;
    }

    public int getBoleta() {
        return this.boleta;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demoA = new Demo(20);
        Demo demoB = new Demo(20);

        System.out.println(demoA.equals(demoB));
        System.out.println(demoA.hashCode());
        System.out.println(demoB.hashCode());
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ((o instanceof Demo) && (((Demo) o).getBoleta() == this.boleta)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Esto da como resultado:

> true
>
> 1414159026
>
> 1569228633

Regresa **true** porque estos objetos son iguales, debido a que se sobrescribió el método equals. Si son considerados iguales por equals, esto se reflejará al utilizarse en las colecciones de tipo Hash. Lo que se puede ver en la salida de este código es que a pesar de que ambos objetos son iguales, el hashcode no es igual. Esto es porque no se ha sobrescrito el método hashCode.

Sobreescribiendo **HashCode**

A continuación se sobre escribe el metodo hashCode, siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.boleta;
    return hash;
    }
```

Y ahora la salida será :

> true
>
> 699
>
> 699

Lo cual nos dice que estos métodos son iguales según **equals**, y que además tienen el mismo numero **hashcode**.

Este método hashCode regresara consistentemente el mismo valor, siempre y cuando el campo `boleta` no cambie. Cada desarrollador puede implementar de diferente manera igualmente validas, correctas y eficientes este método. Lo que debes de tener en mente al sobrescribir este método es que si para sobrescribir el método utilizas variables de instancia (en este ejemplo **boleta**), también debes utilizar variables de instancia para generar un hashcode correcto. En el caso de las constantes que se utilizan en el ejemplo de arriba, se recomienda utilizar números primos, para una mejor distribución del hashcode generado.

El uso principal del hashcode, es como ya lo mencione arriba, cuando se manejan colecciones de tipo **Hash**. La forma en como operan las colecciones de este tipo es a grandes rasgos la siguiente: Las colecciones de tipo Hash almacenan los objetos en lugares llamados baldes, de acuerdo al numero obtenido por el método hashCode.

**Reglas que sigue el método hashCode**

- Si el método hashCode es invocado en múltiples ocasiones durante la
  ejecución de una aplicación, debe regresar consistentemente el mismo
  valor entero, esto si la información utilizada para calcular el
  hashcode no ha cambiado entre invocación e invocación del método
  hashCode.
- Si dos objetos son iguales según el método equals, entonces la
  llamada al método hashCode debe regresar el mismo hashcode.
- No es requerido que si dos métodos no son iguales según el método
  equals, tengan diferentes valores hashcode.

**Ojo**

1. Si dos métodos son iguales según el método equals, el método
   hashCode debe regresar el mismo entero para ambos métodos. Sin
   embargo, si el métodos equals dice que dos métodos no son iguales,
   el método hashCode puede o no regresar el mismo entero.
2. Retornar un valor fijo en un método hashCode es una mala idea, ya
   que tendrás múltiples objetos con el mismo valor hashcode, lo cual
   no ayuda en nada a la hora de trabajar con colecciones de tipo Hash.
3. Si utilizas variables de clase de tipo transient para generar un
   hashcode, serializas el objeto en cuestión y quieres recuperar el
   hashcode de ese método, te encontraras con que el hashcode será
   diferente al hashcode con que se serializó el objeto. Ya que este
   tipo de variables no se serializa. Por eso es una mala idea utilizar
   variables transient para generar el hashcode.

> Respondiendo a tu comentario:

Si recordamos un poco los básicos de java, vemos que si definimos una variable de tipo  primitiva  `int var = 4;` ,  está se almacena en la memoria de acceso rápido `Stack`. Ahora si declaramos una objeto, este es almacenado en la memoria de `Heap` y la referencia a esta dirección de memoria se almacena en `Stack`.

Dicho lo anterior, cuando invocas en método **HashCode**, te estará regresando la `localización en la memoria HEAP` de ese objeto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero ,me gustaria que digas si en verdad devuelve una representacion numerica de la direccion de memoria en la que se encuentra ubicado el objeto ...claro por defecto

Comment: @ProgramadorJava actualice mi respuesta. Saludos